# How to click button and open window to send email in c#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, email

I want to create a button so that user can click and it will open a small new window where they can send email. This window will have "From", "To", "Subject", "Content" fields and all of that will have default text, user can edit them (except for "From" field). See image below:

[image]

What I tried:

I created an email form by:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
</div>
<p>
From:<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</p>
To:<asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<p>
Subject:<asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</p>
Content:<asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I try to link this form with my current code:
Current code: I can send email by this code:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtpclientaddresshere");
mail.From = new MailAddress("defaultFromEmail@domain.com");
mail.To.Add("email1@yahoo.com,email2@yahoo.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail";
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mysmtpserver@something.com", "");
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Now I don't know is this right to use the form above for email window purpose? And how could I format and link all the fields to my working code?

Comment: Well I do it that way, except that I store my password encrypted in the web.config.. Atrough this is should be at Codereview, I'm waiting for some good alternatives

Comment: How do I link the fields in each form ?

Answer (score 2):

What I have done is like this:

```
public void SendEmail(string _from, string _fromDisplayName, string _to, string _toDisplayName, string _subject, string _body, string _password)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient _smtp = new SmtpClient();

            MailMessage _message = new MailMessage();

            _message.From = new MailAddress(_from, _fromDisplayName); // Your email address and your full name

            _message.To.Add(new MailAddress(_to, _toDisplayName)); // The recipient email address and the recipient full name // Cannot be edited

            _message.Subject = _subject; // The subject of the email
            _message.Body = _body; // The body of the email

            _smtp.Port = 587; // Google mail port
            _smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Google mail address
            _smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            _smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            _smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_from, _password); // Login the gmail using your email address and password

            _smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            _smtp.Send(_message);

            ShowMessageBox("Your message has been successfully sent.", "Success", 2);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessageBox("Message : " + ex.Message + "\n\nEither your e-mail or password incorrect. (Are you using Gmail account?)", "Error", 1);
        }
    }
```

And I am using it like this:

```
SendEmail(textBox2.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox3.Text, "YOUR_FULL_NAME", textBox4.Text, textBox6.Text, "YOUR_EMAIL_PASSWORD");
```

Here is the image:

[image]

(Although I am using WinForms and not Windows Presentation Forms).

May this answer would help you.

Cheers!

Comment: Could you share me the code of WinForms (the image) ?

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 If i change to different version I will get some problems in my project

Comment: For the bunch of textBoxes shown on the image of my answer, you just have to drag-and-drop. .Net does not matter on this situation, if you already using .Net 3.5, keep using that, not required to change .Net version. If you didn't know how to do that, find tutorial on youtube, there are bunch of tutorials on how to do drag-and-drop textBoxes on Windows Forms. Note: Please accept my answer if you found this is what you are looking for. Thank you

Comment: Yes, sure I will accept it as the answer once I can implement it on my side. I really believe it depends on .net version since I do not have any Windows Forms templates to add. May be the project framework is depend on .net framework. I do not know how to add windows forms then. I did tried this fix but it doesn't help (https://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/). If have that template, I will follow this tutorial to add the form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9L85OBo1c4

Comment: Not sure if I can really help you, because since I installed Visual Studio 2010 (for making the installer only) and 2013, both of the software have windows forms already. Those problem of yours never happened to me.

Comment: Looks like someone else also has this problem: http://www.gidforums.com/t-4494.html. But they never mention how to fix it...

Comment: Try to uninstall all of components that installed on your computer since you install Visual Studio, then after successful uninstall Visual Studio, restart the computer, and then try to install Visual Studio again with all of components selected (Full Features) and check if there no message say that like "some of the components may not be installed" during the installation process. May be the problem is that when you install Visual Studio for the first time, you have not check some of the components or there is a warning and you have ignored it.